# How to notify table-data change to a client program?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have an application that access data resident in a central DB server and more than one user access data from client machines networked with the DB server.

Suppose two client machines are running a copy of the application and two users are accessing the same DB table.

How can I automatically refresh the data on the GUI, that is being viewed by one client, as soon as a change is made by another client in the DB table-data?

Which technology should be used to solve this particular scenario in .net?

WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a notification push model. You'd have to create seperate connections from the server back to each client. Lots of hard work. WCF / sockets for this. Comet in a web server environment.

Much easier way to do this is to poll the server every 15 seconds or so from the client and check if there has been an update. Store a last updated timestamp on the server and if it is greater than the timestamp you have then do a refresh.