# update user interface when database data is changed

Tags: c#

is there any way possible where a control on the form (ex: datagrid) is automatically updated once a data has been inserted on the Database?

#### Example:

1. Person A has a dashboard on his computer which monitors a high level inventory breakdown.
2. Person B, C, and D added a new item to the inventory database respectively.
3. Person B, C, and D's action should immediately reflect on Person A's (realtime) with no timers, intervals, or manual refresh.

is it possible to achieve this via C# WinForms? I've studied and tried things about SignalR but i don't think its that of what i want/need.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2724944/2417602

Comment: Did you tried SqlDependency
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your DB is MSSQL.

I'm sorry to say but there is NO way you can achieve what you want without hitting SQL DB with polling requests. You may try [SQLDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency) as mentioned by @Cyber Progs in the comment, but I still don't think that will do much good. But hey, trying does no harm :) So go for it.

SQL is more of a kind where *you get what you ask*. Not the other way around. So unless and until you make a polling request to the DB to get the details of whatever table you want by using a `timer` or `manual refresh`, SQL by itself won't pass an update to your program.

As you have tried and left `SignalR`, I would suggest to use a `Timer` + `Multithreading`. Apart from that I don't see a way more suitable for what you require to be achieved.

Else a more convenient option would be to use `FileSystemWatcher` which resides in `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`.
What you can do is create a `SQL Trigger` over the table that you want to get notified about.

This trigger would eventually do nothing but change(modify) a *local/network file* whenever an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` query has been run.

The file itself would have nothing in its content, it's just that its modified date would change on every `Trigger` run.

You can now code in your application using `FileSystemWatcher` to watch for this(local/network) file. If it's modified just do a quick poll to the DB and fetch the latest data.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using SignalR and SQL event listeners.

Step 1:
You could define your entity model in c# (there are tools to do reverse engineering which would save you time writing the context yourself).

Step 2:
Configure SignalR Hub. Store all user connections in an objects, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) has a basic tutorial how to do that.

Step 3:
You can then override *SaveChangesAsync* method, do some checks inside to determine whats being chanegd and if its the model that you are interested in you can fire the changes to a SIgnalR hub method and that will push all the changes to a client side JS.

Once you received it in JS you can perform the changes to the datagrid.